# Is it possible to disable bool operator<(float,int)

Tags: c++

Can I, in C++, disable or force an explicit cast in `operator<` when comparing integer and floating types? Using `operator<` between integer and float types can easily lead to bugs in quantitative code. I tried `bool operator<(double, int) = delete;` but it expects one of the types to be a class or enum. How do I make the below fail to compile with a type error?

```
int main()
{
    if (3.0 < 4)
    {
        std::cout << "X" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Y" << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It cannot be done natively. But you can look into various external tests.

Comment: Nuts. Do you mean taking a static analysis approach?

Comment: I don't see the applicability of being able to do this. It's really a contract between the programmer and the compiler to not do stupid things. The end-client can't touch this.

Comment: In quant finance it's very common to have business users doing dev. I clean up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not possible to change the behaviour of built-in operators. You will have to detect this situation via compiler warnings or other code analysis tools.